# C# PBKDF2 Implementation

Tags: c#, cryptography, pbkdf2

This is my first time implementing password hashing. I am trying to implement PBKDF2 using C#. After doing some research this is what I came up with.

```
public static byte[] GenerateSalt()
{
    using (var randomNumberGenerator = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        var salt = new byte[32];
        randomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(salt);

        return salt;
    }
}

public static byte[] HashPassword(byte[] password, byte[] salt, int iterations)
{
    using (var rfc2898 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, iterations))
    {
        return rfc2898.GetBytes(32);
    }
}

public static bool CompareByteArrays(byte[] array1, byte[] array2)
{
    if (array1.Length != array2.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
    {
        if (array1[i] != array2[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

In my database I would store the hash password and salt. I was wondering if I should also store the iterations? After researching it looked like this number should increase ever so often so I was hoping to come up with a dynamic way to do this. I was not sure this would give someone a benefit if they stole the database and knew how many iterations I was doing.

Comment: I tend to store a "version" along with my encoded bytes. Consider that you do not need to expose the salt and iteration count (or version of algorithm) as separate columns. You could pack that information into the byte array that holds the password, and extract the individual components separately.

Comment: You're saying have a single column in the database table and have it just store a string like "HashedPassword:Salt:Iterations" per user?

Comment: You don't even have to do that. Consider that your password is in a byte array, and there's no reason other data can't be in that byte array too. Perhaps your version is the first X bytes, and your salt is the next Y bytes, and then everything after that is the password, or however you feel you need to chunk it up. Then convert the byte array to Base64 string or something and store that in DB. When unpacking, convert from Base64 string back to byte array, and then extract the individual components from their known positions in the byte array.

Comment: The number of iterations is not normally considered secret (in PKCS#5 encryption you have to transmit it as part of the unencrypted data, after all).  In the same column, different columns, it's just up to whatever is easiest for your application to process.